# Wordpress блог внутри сайта

Tags: wordpress

Доброго времени суток. Есть портал на wordpress, и есть блог на wordpress, который лежит на отдельном домене. У первого и второго разный шаблон. Есть ли какая-то возможность перенести блог на портал wordpress'a? То есть получится, что портал на wordpress'e, но в нем будет перенесенный блог со своим дизайном. Как это лучше сделать? Использовать дочерние темы или есть какие-то другие варианты?

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться плагином [Multiple themes](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/jonradio-multiple-themes/). Он позволяет установить несколько тем и назначить условия, когда какую использовать. Вот [статья с пояснениями](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-use-multiple-themes-for-pages-in-wordpress/) на английском.

Использовал этот плагин, чтобы на одном вордпрессе разным заказчикам показывать разные темы. Но это оказалось удобно только на предварительных переговорах. Как только начинаются доработки, трудно добиться, чтобы изменения в одной части сайта совсем не трогали всё остальное.

Поэтому для вашей задачи рекомендую подумать не над двумя темами на одном сайте, а над разными шаблонами внутри одной темы.

Почитайте, например, [статью на wp-kama.ru](https://wp-kama.ru/id_8577/shablony-stranitsy-dlya-tipov-zapisej-v-wp-4-7.html):

> С версии WordPress 4.7 функционал шаблонов страниц расширился. И теперь можно создавать шаблоны для страниц любого типа.

Answer (score 1):

В WordPress есть специальный механизм для этого - мультисайт. В режиме мультисайта входящие в него сайты могут быть размещены на разных доменах и иметь разные темы.

Мультисайт хранит данные о своих сайтах в единой базе, что позволяет легко организовывать взаимодействие и обмен данными между сайтами. В пользовательском коде можно переключить используемый сайт (блог) с помощью функции [switch_to_blog()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/switch_to_blog) и записать данные, полученные с одного сайта, в раздел базы данных другого сайта.

Answer (score 0):

блог вроде состоит из записей, записи можно импортировать через инструменты Word Press (импорт/экспорт) и настроить страницу блога в Настройках -> Чтение

Comment: Проблема даже не в записях, их перенести не трудно. Проблема в том, что текущая тема на блоге (Sparking) отдельная самостоятельная тема. А на портале другая тема.Вот и получается что хочется соединить блог с порталом, но чтоб на блоге была своя тема, а на портале своя.

Comment: думаю, что так сделать не получится ) одна тема на один сайт как я понимаю

Answer (score 0):

> Как это лучше сделать?

Если не интересует домен "блога", то можно его перенести на поддомен "портала".